# System.Windows.DependencyObject WindowsBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

On my computer the ASP.Net site is running. But when I copied the files to the server there is this error:

> CS0012: Tipo 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' está definido em um assembly que não é usado como referência. Adicione uma referência ao assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly WindowsBase is missing. If you are developing the software then add WindowsBase to the references.

Alternatively you could look at the ASP.NET site  section from Web.config, [as detailed in this blog](http://www.projectenvision.com/blog/4/CS0012-The-type-System-Data-Objects-DataClasses-EntityObject-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced). Add the following

```
<add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```